# Category , lie algebras ....

Tags: reference-request, lie-algebras

I want a reference book about Lie algebras that have the definition of universal enveloping algebra by the categorical point of view. All references that i found use the construction by the quotient of the tensor algebra and one especific ideal.

Answer (score 1):

An internet-accessible note that emphasizes a bit more the characterization, rather than *construction*, is in my course notes, http://www.math.umn.edu/~garrett/m/mfms/notes_2013-14/11d_diffops.pdf

In my experience, orthodox texts don't so much emphasize this viewpoint, because they're (misguidedly, in my opinion) trying to be "elementary", and, given the standard curriculum, even the mildest most innocent categorical notions are viewed with suspicion, as though they were an additional burden rather than useful.

Serre's 1964 (?) Harvard notes, published by Benjamin long ago, form an orthodox source more progressive in this regard than many since.

Comment: (+1) for the answer and (+ million) for: "... more progressive in this regard than many since". Not only in Lie theory but also in other areas some of the more recent books are afraid to present even mildly categorical perspectives.

Comment: :) @IttayWeiss, the inertia and intellectual conservatism of the mathematical community/establishment is amazing. I speculate that this tendency is statistically correlated with common psychological tendencies that have attracted (rightly-or-wrongly) people to math in the first place, e.g., affection for "permanent correctness" which gets over-interpreted to supposedly entail that discussion and interpretation are "done". Or the pseudo-objectiveness of mathematics. Many similar popular conceits.